# Counts of congruent numbers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am compiling a table of the total number of congruent numbers $\le 10^{n}$ (see OEIS 274403: http://oeis.org/A274403). So far I have evaluated up to $n = 7$.
My question is - Are there computer readable lists of congruent numbers available as open access $\ge 10^7$? If so what is the URL? Alternatively can anyone provide counts of congruent numbers $\le 10^8, 10^9$ etc?

Comment: Are you willing to assume the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture or not? If you are (and the OEIS link you gave does), then the paper [here](http://www.warwick.ac.uk/~masfaw/congruent.pdf) has some useful tables (just of the counts). If not, then the problem is a good bit harder.

Comment: @Jeremy: Yes BSD conjecture is assumed. Thank you for the URL. Now need $10^8$ counts for {$1,2,3$} mod $8$ to complete the sequence up to $10^{12}$. Can anyone provide this?